# Is sodium hypochlorite solution an ionic solution - does it conduct current?

Tags: aqueous-solution, ionic-compounds, conductivity

Does an aqueous solution of sodium hypochlorite conduct current?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is a solution of an ionic salt. a [table](http://www.forp.usp.br/restauradora/Trabalhos/prnaclo.html) lists electrical conductivity at various concentrations.